# In Sengoku, what is the starting level of wealth?

Tags: character-creation, fuzion, sengoku

I came across this question answering [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104434/what-is-the-correct-order-to-build-a-character/).  Per R.A.W.:

> Characters are assumed to be "lower middle class" within their caste; the character has enough to get by - a steady job, clothes his back *[sic]* and simple tools to ply his trade (i.e., starting equipment) - and a disposable income of 10 coins per year.  The *Wealth* perk boosts one's lifestyle. Spending 1 OP places you comfortably in the middle class.

This is followed by a few paragraphs of examples and clarification, as well as a chart.  The rules question comes from the discrepancy between the rules text and the explanation text, which imply three different starting wealth levels:

- *Wealth 0:* Per the Fuzion core rules, and the rules on page 115, you have *no* rank in *any* perk unless you purchase it - Wealth 0, effectively.  However, that creates an error R.A.W., since Sengoku requires an entry on the Wealth table to get money during character creation.
- *Wealth 1:* Per the Template rules on page 122, which says all characters have a default level 1 of Wealth.  However, the Template rules are also designed around pre-spending OP for simplicity, so it could be that the Template rules automatically sink one OP into Wealth.
- *Wealth 2:* The explanation text for the Wealth perk (p. 116) states that by default, you have a "disposable income of 10 coins per year" - that matches up with the wealth table's Level 2.

The simplest explanation I can think of would be that there's a misprint in the Wealth table on page 117 and that it's supposed to be 0-indexed, not 1-indexed... but that still wouldn't solve the discrepancies, and still wouldn't set a set rule.

I tried to search on the GRG forums, only to find they seem to have been deleted.

Comment: There are some glaring inconsistencies in the wealth category.

Answer (score 2):

### Player characters have 0 wealth but get an income buff.

As noted, they have 10 income a year, a job, clothes, and equipment. They don't have a place to own, and can't purchase common goods. This means they have a lot of disposable income, but don't have a fixed abode which makes sense for the setting where you have wandering warriors doing quests. They are wealth 0, which as you noted is the default number for any perk you don't buy.

If they purchase wealth 1, they get a total of 11 income and a place to live and can buy common things. This is in the campaign section of the rules for player characters.

### NPCs start with 1 wealth for free

They start with 1 income and a place and common things. They don't have 10 income a year. They're not special like player characters. This section is clearly signposted as for NPCs, not player characters.

### There's no contradiction, just player characters have a buff to 0 wealth

Presumably the developers wanted players to have some free cash to spend so they could buy cool japanese goods. As such, they get extra free cash by default, but no home or non essential personal goods.